# PHP: Uploading 3gp video files

Tags: php, video, mime-types

I want to upload .3gp video files to server via PHP code. I checked the mime type of 3gp video files by 'echo' video type of file, it gives it as `application/octet-stream`.

I have added a check below to restrict it to only few video format files, as below:

```
if($_video_type != 'video/x-ms-wmv' && $_video_type != 'application/octet-stream' && $_video_type != 'video/avi' && $_video_type != 'video/mpeg'){
    $_error_videotitle = 'Only WMV, MP4, MPEG, FLV, 3GP videos are allowed';
    $is_errors = true;
}
```

But its not uploading 3gp file, it still giving error :(

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Well, what happens? What does `$_video_type` contain?

Comment: It should also be noted that these headers are set by the client (browser), so I wouldn't necessarily rely on them being consistent.

Comment: @middaparka then what should I do, what you suggest?

Comment: @Prashant Being realistic, you'll need to allow the user to upload pretty much anything and then attempt to handle it on the server. (Hard to know how without knowing what you're attempting to achieve, but there's likely to be some command line tools out there that could verify the file format.)

Comment: @middaparka, I am just trying to upload video files from a simple PHP form, I have to check its actually the video file (wmv, 3gp, flv etc) which we want to allow for upload or not.

Comment: @Prashant In that case you might want to search for a command line tool that can identify video files - if it recognises the file then chances are it's a valid video. Anything else is just speculation.

Comment: yes, I am planning to use ffmpeg, but its giving some error when installing it in my TurnKeyLinux setup, I am trying to resolve the installation issue. But till then I need something which can serve the page properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you copy pasted your code here? If so, then note that you have an additional blank space in the end.

```
'application/octet-stream '
```

Comment: Did you edit the question? First time when I saw, there was an additional space, now its gone!  Check in your original code to see if there is any additional space

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very good check.

Depending on the MIME type (assumably) given by PHP file info is not good at all because it doesn't actually check the contents so much, or not at all...

The MIME type is usually checked by the extension, and there are only few basic extensions supported...

Anything that is defined as "application/octet-stream" is basically in format UNKNOWN to PHP / anything else. Most browsers will just download these kinds of files.

So for actual type and WORKING MIME detection I would suggest to first check the extension, and then a codec that should be contained in a file of that kind. If the headers don't match, the file is not valid... Also - for the headers just search for "3gp format" for example - it is very easy to find formats on most codecs just in Google. If you can't find it like that, check this useful page: [Multimedia Wiki](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/)